# Argument (Controller) is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

After googling for an hour and searching in Stackoverflow I cannot get the answer. I am new to angular and this is just a practice but i cannot make it work. I get this error in the console:

> Error: Argument 'StoreController as store' is not a function, got
>   undefined.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>


</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <h2>{{store.employee.name}}</h2>
        <h3>{{store.employee.age}}</h3> 
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js file:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('StoreController', function() {
        this.employee = { 
            name: 'John',
            age: 32
        };
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Angular version is outdated. You're currently using 1.0.7. The `controllerAs` construct was only added in version 1.2. You should up your version to the latest.